# Microsoft Excel converts all numbers to Scientific Notations

Tags: excel, scientific-notation

Whenever I enter any integer in Excel it converts it to Scientific notation,
Below is the result when I add 1, 2, 3:

[image]

 
How do I stop this?
If I type `1.` it considers it as integer.

Comment: If you type 1 it considers it as an integer, so how are you adding 1,2,3 to your spreadsheet. Also what is the cell format?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. Found the culprit.
The following setting was enabled somehow in File-> Options-> Advanced 
and set to 20 decimal places.
[image]